# In small grid, toolPanel menu is clipped

Tags: ag-grid

The [ag-grid popupParent](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/#popup-parent) documentation/plunker talks about setting popupParent so that context menus have room to display:

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{field: 'num', headerName:'A'}]
    rowData: [{num:'1'},{num:'2'},{num:'3'],
    popupParent: document.querySelector("body")
};
```

This affects contextMenu items and columnMenu items, but it does not appear to affect toolPanel.  In [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QaWPuLsThnp1J0zA9Yds?p=preview), you can see the issue I am having.

Is there another gridOption I should be using to fix this?